# Create scroll of custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to create an area on an HTML homepage (HTML site that contains WP pages) that presents through an iframe or other, the titles of all posts for one custom post type.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made the home-page of your site a WordPress page, you could just create a page-template for that home page.

Within that page template you could have all of your HTML, as well as the loops for showing your posts or pages or whatever else.

Comment: Adam - thank you!  I'm taking your suggestion and am going to rework the HTML homepage into a WP page.  Here's what I would love your advice on - should I install WP in the root directory to power the homepage & keep the current WP installation (in a folder called 'listings') for one regular and one custom post type, or try to use one installation?  I also want to add a new post (News). That would result in 2 separate admin areas for the client - one for listings and one for news items.  Do you have any thoughts on what makes the most sense from a management perspective?  Thank you in advance~

Comment: Hi Mktggirl. I would say that a single install of WordPress could easily manage everything you want to do. 
Pages> could handle all of your static pages such as home or contact or about...and Custom Post Types for News and Listings and whatever other types you need. Regular posts for whatever you are using them for now.   That way there is just one admin area to handle everything

Comment: Thank you, Adam - that's the route I'm taking and it's working just fine!